# How do I verify that at least one checkbox is checked, and send the values of checked checkboxes in an email?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form where a customer is to fill out details regarding a job:

```
    <form id="contact-form">
      <p>Use the form below to send us a message.</p>
          <input  id="form-name" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Name" required />
          <input id="form-email" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Email" required />
          <input id="form-phone" class="form-input" type="text"  placeholder="Phone" required />
          <input id="form-address" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Address" required />
          <input id="form-postcode" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Postcode" required />
          <fieldset>
            <h4>Do you own the property?</h4>
            <input type="radio" id="radiooption1" name="form-ownership" value="Yes">
            <label for="radiooption1">Yes</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" id="radiooption2" name="form-ownership" value="No">
            <label for="radiooption2">No</label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <h4>What services are you interested in?</h4>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkoption1" name="form-services" value="Option1">
            <label for="checkoption1"> Option1</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkoption2" name="form-services" value="Option2">
            <label for="checkoption2"> Option2</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkoption3" name="form-services" value="Option3">
            <label for="checkoption3"> Option3</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkoption4" name="form-services" value="Option4">
            <label for="checkoption4"> Option4</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkoption5" name="form-services" value="Option5">
            <label for="checkoption5"> Option5</label>
          </fieldset>
      <p id="question"></p>
      <input type="text" class="form-input" id="form-answer">
      <h3 id="submit-btn" onClick="check_form()" >Submit</h3>
      <p id="caution-text" ></p>
    </form>
```

And this is the Javascript I am running to verify and send the code

```
// Form Setup

// - 

function check_form() {

  if ($('#form-answer').val() == c) {
    // - Submit
    $('#question').html('correct');
    $('#form-answer').css({
      'background-color': '#b5d46c',
      'color': '#fff'
    });
    $('#caution-text').html('');

    form_check();
  } else {
    // - Dont Submit
    $('#caution-text').html('Answer incorrect.');
    $('#form-answer').css({
      'background-color': '#DB6E24',
      'color': '#fff'
    });
  }

}

// -

// -

// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

$('#form-name').change(function () {
  btn_rdy_check();
});
$('#form-email').change(function () {
  btn_rdy_check();
});
$('#form-phone').change(function () {
  btn_rdy_check();
});
$('#form-address').change(function () {
  btn_rdy_check();
});
$('#form-postcode').change(function () {
  btn_rdy_check();
});
$('#form-message').change(function () {
  btn_rdy_check();
});

// - - - -

function btn_rdy_check() {
  if (($('#form-name').val() !== "") && ($('#form-email').val() !== "") && ($('#form-phone').val() !== "") && ($('#form-message').val() !== "") && ($('#form-address').val() !== "") && ($('#form-postcode').val() !== "")) {
    // - 

    $('#submit-btn').css({
      'background-color': '#3fd44a'
    });
  } else {
    $('#submit-btn').css({
      'background-color': '#ccc'
    });
  }
}

// - - - -

var checkValue = "";


function getcheckvalue() {
  var markedCheckbox = document.getElementsByName('form-services');

  for (var checkbox of markedCheckbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      checkValue = (checkValue + checkbox.value + ', ');
    }
  }
  if (checkValue.length < 1) {
    checkValue = 'No services selected';
  }
}



function atLeastOne() {
// get all the checkboxes by their class name
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.form-services');

let atLeastOneChecked = false;


  // loop through all the checkboxes and check if at least one is checked
  for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      // at least one checkbox is checked
      atLeastOneChecked = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function form_check() {
  // - Check values.

  getcheckvalue();

  console.log('checking content');

  // -                                      

  if ($('#form-name').val() !== "") {
    // - 

    console.log('name entered');
  } else {
    console.log('name not entered');
  }

  if ($('#form-postcode').val() !== "") {
    // - 

    console.log('postcode entered');
  } else {
    console.log('postcode not entered');
  }

  // -

  if ($('#form-email').val() !== "") {
    // -

    console.log('email entered');
  } else {
    console.log('email not entered');
  }

  if ($('#form-address').val() !== "") {
    // -

    console.log('address entered');
  } else {
    console.log('address not entered');
  }

  if ($('#form-postcode').val() !== "") {
    // -

    console.log('postcode entered');
  } else {
    console.log('postcode not entered');
  }

  // -

  if ($('#form-phone').val() !== "") {
    // - 
    console.log('phone entered');
  } else {
    console.log('phone not entered');
  }
    
  if ($(atLeastOneChecked = true)) {
    // - 
    console.log('services selected');
  } else {
    console.log('services not selected');
  }

  //  if ($(checkValue.includes('No services selected'))) {
  //    console.log('services not selected');
  //  } else {
  //   console.log('services selected')
  // }


  // -

  // Check all

  if (($('#form-name').val() !== "") && ($('#form-email').val() !== "") && ($('#form-phone').val() !== "") && ($('#form-message').val() !== "") && ($('#form-address').val() !== "") && ($('#form-postcode').val() !== "") && ($(atLeastOneChecked).boolValue == "True")) {
    // - 


    send_msg();

  }

  // -                                  

}

var tmp = "";

function send_msg() {
  console.log('sending message');

  // - Send message.
  // - 

  tmp = "";

  tmp += "<p>Name : " + $('#form-name').val() + "</p>";
  tmp += "<p>Email : " + $('#form-email').val() + "</p>";
  tmp += "<p>Phone : " + $('#form-phone').val() + "</p>";
  tmp += "<p>Address : " + $('#form-address').val() + "</p>";
  tmp += "<p>Postcode : " + $('#form-postcode').val() + "</p>";
  tmp += "<p>Do you own the property? : " + document.querySelector('input[name="form-ownership"]:checked').value; + "</p>";
  tmp += "<p>What services are you interested in? : " + String(checkValue); + "</p>";

  var data = {
    details: tmp,
    valid: 'true',
    reply: $('#form-email').val()
  };

  // -

  jQuery.post('assets/form/send.php', data, function (response) {
    console.log(response);

    jQuery('#contact-form').html('<h3>Enquiry sent...</h3>');

  });
}
```

I was able to initially get the email to send with the contents using the function getCheckValue(), but I could not get the form to refuse to send if no checkboxes were selected. This is also a concern with the radio boxes. How do I get this validation to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function atLeastOne() isn't returning any value, you should rewrite it like this:

```
function atLeastOne() {
    // get all the checkboxes by their class name
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('form-services');
    // loop through all the checkboxes and check if at least one is checked
    for (let checkbox of checkboxes) {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then the first line of check_form();

```
if (!atLeastOne()) {
    alert('No checkboxes selected');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was just what I needed! The ! just needed to be moved inside the bracket.

Comment: You're right, I updated the answer, thank you. By the way, you can also upvote my answer besides accepting it ;-)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet, when I get enough I'll come back and upvote you. Thanks again!

Comment: Understood, it's not necessary then ;-)